# No Wireless Extension on my Windows 10 Virtual Machine

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, virtual-machine, wireless-bridge

I installed a Windows 10 Virtual Machine. I enabled Network Adapter, Attached to : Bridged Adapter, Name : wlp6s0. I also installed the VirtualBox Extension Pack. The problem is I can't access the networks on my VM. I installed bash/ubuntu on my VM and with `iwconfig`, I obtained `No Wireless Extension`. How can I fix that?

Comment: It's a virtual wired NIC, not a wireless one.

Comment: @gronostaj Can you extend your answer? I am really not a specialist with VMs.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough knowledge about your situation nor enough time to type a proper answer. This hint should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Go to the Virtual Box settings for your guest machine and ensure it has been set for NAT or Bridged - your choice. Then in the guest machine, go to the Network Settings and see if the wired setting works. That is normally true for any guest machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you use NAT or Bridge connections , most hypervisors virtualize connection as wired connection for guest os. you can configure it as a simple LAN (it's not a wifi connection!). 
If you want to have a wireless connection **Insert a new physical media** like a wireless USB adaptor directly to your guest OS, then configure it.