# linux on virtual machine, on windows, cant detect wireless extensions when using iwconfig

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, virtualbox

Im using a virtual machine running on windows.
The virtual machine is using linux ubuntu. I am connected to my windows internet on the virtual machine but when I run iwconfig the only thing that shows is

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.
lo        no wireless extensions.
```

I have searched and read about 10 different posts on this such as [No Wireless Extension on my Windows 10 Virtual Machine](https://superuser.com/questions/1535393/no-wireless-extension-on-my-windows-10-virtual-machine). But the only thing that is suggested is to connect a wireless USB adaptor and connect that USB to the VM. Is there no way to use the wireless connection built in to my laptop?

Thanks

Comment: No, there isn't. That's how virtualization works. In the VM all the OS can "see" is the virtualized hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Linux Networking as a Virtual Machine works perfectly well. I have both Ubuntu and Kali machines and both are connected to the Host Network which appears in a VM as an Ethernet Connection, not wireless. That is how a VM works (VMware, Hyper-V and VBOX). It uses the virtualized hardware that the VM App provides.

In other words, you cannot (as you asked) use the Host wireless connection directly. In most cases you do not need to. See the end note for using special purpose USB pass through.

The Host can have a Wired or Wireless connection (mine is wireless) but the VM will show up as Ethernet.

Check your VM Network Settings and make sure (to begin with) that you are using a NAT connection.

It appears you may have set the VM for Host Only.

Make sure about NAT (restart the VM if you changed this) and then in a terminal do an ifconfig and make sure about this first section which will tell you what IP address you have (likely 192.168.xxx.yyy)

Make sure of all the above and your VM will work normally and have Internet.

**Note:**  If you wish to have a Wireless connection in the Virtual Machine for a particular purpose, you can use a USB Wireless Card and USB Pass through on VMware or VBOX (not readily available in Hyper-V).

However this is not a requirement for basic networking and usually not needed.